# Updating nested array n1ql

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

The sample doc, I am trying to work with is:

```
{
   "name": "level1",
   "childLevel1": [
    {
       "name": "level2",
       "childLevel2": [
       {
          "name": "level3",
          "childLevel3": [
          {
               "name": "level4",
               "attribute1": "data"
          }
          ]
        }
        ]
     }
     ]
}
```

What we want to do is, with n1ql add one more array element to "childLevel3". I have tried the reference to https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/update.html

I was able to add a regular attribute to childLevel2 but after that it was not working. This is the query I have been trying out.

```
Update sample
set child2.childLevel3 = ARRAY_PUT(child2.childLevel3, {'attribute' : 'data2'})
FOR child2 in child1.childLevel2 when child2.name == "level3" END
for child1 in childLevel1 when childLevel1.name == 'level2' END
WHERE name == 'level1'
```

But it gives me error on parsing, I tried other ways too but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
UPDATE sample
SET child2.childLevel3 = ARRAY_PUT(child2.childLevel3, {'attribute' : 'data2'})
    FOR child2 in child1.childLevel2 
    FOR child1 in childLevel1
    WHEN childLevel1.name == 'level2' AND child2.name == "level3"
    END
WHERE name == 'level1';
```

Comment: it does not add anything, it doesn't give any error

Answer (score 0):

I had to update an object within a nested array, recently in Couchbase. The answer above helped me to formulate this query in a bucket called "metadata". The data structure is:

```
{
    "documentMetadata": {
        "documentId": "42"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "type": "FileStaging",
            "status": "NOT STARTED"
        }
    ],
    "type": "runLog"
}
```

The query that worked for me:

```
UPDATE metadata 
SET res.status = 'QUEUED'
    FOR res in results 
    WHEN res.type = 'FileStaging'
    END
WHERE type = 'runLog'
AND documentMetadata.documentId = '42'
```